# count NSArray from another class

Tags: ios, objective-c

Very basic question here...

I have 2 classes and I want to keep an NSArray in one class and access it in different class.

**Questions.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Questions : NSObject
@property NSMutableArray *questions;
-(void) questionMethod;
@end
```

**Questions.m**

```
#import "Questions.h"
@implementation Questions
-(void) questionMethod {
    NSArray *questionBank = [4,5,6];
}
@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "Questions.h"
-(void)generateRandomQuestionOrder {
    Questions *questions = [[Questions alloc] init];
}
```

How do I count the values of questionBank array in generateRandomQuestionOrder method?

Comment: in `ViewController.m`, you're basically creating a new instance of the `Questions` class and going any further would give you a count of 0 anyways. Easy and quick way would be to make `Questions` a singleton class so you can modify/access it's contents from any class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the best naming convention but take a look at the following example. You declare a public property in the Questions object and access it from the controller after you initialised a new object there. You may consider declaring it readonly and set it to readwrite in the private interface extension.

**Questions.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Questions : NSObject
@property NSMutableArray *questions;

@end
```

**Questions.m**

```
#import "Questions.h"
@implementation Questions
-(id) init { 
  if (self = [super init]) {
    _questions = @[4,5,6];
  }
  return self;
}
@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "Questions.h"
-(void)generateRandomQuestionOrder {
    Questions *theQuestions = [[Questions alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"%@", [theQuestions.questions description]); 
}
```

Comment: in questions.m it says: Cannot assign to 'self' a method in the init family

Comment: @MrBr : your Questions.m is probably `-(id) init {` , isn't it ?